# Librosa failing to plot mfcc generated

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa, mfcc

I'm was being able to generate MFCC from system captured audio and plot it, but after some refactor and configuring Tensorflow with CUDA. I used Librosa to generated the mfcc, matplotlib.pyplot with librosa.display to plot the MFCC and sounddevice capturing sound from Stereo mix from windows. The current configuration can create and plot MFCC from sample .wav files but when using system captured sounds it's not able to plot it since its generating a 3D array instead of a 2D when running MFCC. Here is the code that generates and plots

```
N_MFCC = 40 
N_MELS = 40 
N_FFT = 512 
HOP_LENGTH = 160 
MIN_FREQ = 0 
MAX_FREQ = None

def create_mfcc(record, sample_rate):
  features = librosa.feature.mfcc(record, sample_rate, n_fft=N_FFT,n_mfcc=N_MFCC, 
              n_mels=N_MELS,hop_length=HOP_LENGTH,fmin=MIN_FREQ, fmax=MAX_FREQ, htk=False)
  return features

def plot_and_save_mfcc(mfcc_data, file_name, sample_rate):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.title('Current audio MFCC', fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]', fontsize=18)
    librosa_display.specshow(mfcc_data, sr=sample_rate)
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    plt.cla()
```

This generates this stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 63, in main
    start_listening_and_creating_mfcc()
  File "main.py", line 48, in start_listening_and_creating_mfcc
    plot_and_save_mfcc(mfcc_data, conf.DEFAULT_MFCC_IMAGE_NAME.format(image_count), conf.SAMPLE_RATE)
  File "main.py", line 38, in plot_and_save_mfcc
    librosa_display.specshow(mfcc_data, sr=sample_rate)
  File anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py", line 88, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\display.py", line 879, in specshow
    out = axes.pcolormesh(x_coords, y_coords, data, **kwargs)
  File anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1361, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 6183, in pcolormesh
    X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args,
  File anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5671, in _pcolorargs
    nrows, ncols = C.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I did try debug it and change mfcc configuration, but no success. Also did try to reconfigure my environment but this didn't help either.

EDIT: Here is the mfcc.Shapes for the System audio
(48000, 40, 1)
And for the .wav sample files
(40, 122)

As mentioned I left a function out of the question but here is it and the function the is used to load and create mfcc for the .wav files

```py
def create_mfcc_from_file(file_path):
    (signal, sample_rate) = librosa.load(file_path)
    librosa_features = create_mfcc(signal, sample_rate)
    plot_and_save_mfcc(librosa_features, 'mfcc-librosa', sample_rate)

def start_listening_and_creating_mfcc():
    image_count = 0
    while True:
        my_recording = record_window()
        mfcc_data = create_mfcc(my_recording, conf.SAMPLE_RATE)
        plot_and_save_mfcc(mfcc_data, conf.DEFAULT_MFCC_IMAGE_NAME.format(image_count), conf.SAMPLE_RATE)
        wav.write(conf.DEFAULT_MFCC_IMAGE_NAME.format(image_count) + '.wav', conf.SAMPLE_RATE, my_recording)
        image_count += 1
```

Comment: `print(mfcc_data.shape)` to check its shape

Comment: You have left out the most critical function, `start_listening_and_creating_mfcc`

Comment: Just updated the question with the info @JonNordby

Comment: what is my_recording.shape? And the critical function record_window is missing

Comment: For the recording from system audio (48000, 2) and for the `signal` loaded .wav sample file is (19366,)

Comment: And there is your problem - one case returns stereo audio, the other mono. You need to decide whether you want to use mono, or support multiple independent channels

Comment: Even when I changed the config to record system audio as a mono and the record came as (48000, 1) it still produced a (48000, 40, 1)

Comment: Recording the audio as mono and applying a record.flatten() seems to solve the issue but have been wondering how to handle this problem using stereo

Comment: Iterate over the channels

Answer (score 0):

```
def delta(feat, N):
    """Compute delta features from a feature vector sequence.
    :param feat: A numpy array of size (NUMFRAMES by number of features) containing features. Each row holds 1 feature vector.
    :param N: For each frame, calculate delta features based on preceding and following N frames
    :returns: A numpy array of size (NUMFRAMES by number of features) containing delta features. Each row holds 1 delta feature vector.
    """
    if N < 0:
        raise ValueError('N must be an integer >0')
    NUMFRAMES = len(feat)
    denominator = 2 * sum([i**2 for i in range(1, N+1)])
    delta_feat = numpy.empty_like(feat)
    padded = numpy.pad(feat, ((N, N), (0, 0)), mode='edge')   # padded version of feat
    for t in range(NUMFRAMES):
      
        delta_feat[t] = numpy.dot(numpy.arange(-N, N+1), padded[t : t+2*N+1]) / denominator 
        plt.plot(signal, c='c')# [t : t+2*N+1] == [(N+t)-N : (N+t)+N+1]
    return delta_feat
```